# Location-based price in Schema.org

Tags: location, e-commerce, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

My client is a retail store with an online boutique on Magento. I'm implementing Schema.org in Microdata.

The problem comes from the fact that his prices are different depending on the closest city from the user. What "offer" elements do I use in order to set things straight with machines?

My fear is that Google could show the wrong price in the SERP. I don't want to deceive users!

Comment: Maybe http://schema.org/eligibleRegion

Comment: Seems right. Do you know if there is a way to tell machines "around that city". I see I can use ISO_3166 for states/provinces, but the client's price differs by cities .

Comment: That field also accepts a Place, which has the child type [City](http://schema.org/City).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) can have multiple [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) items (via the [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property), exactly for such a purpose.

In the `Offer` item, you use properties that describe in which situation (for whom, when, etc.) the offer is valid. For location-based offers, the [`eligibleRegion`](http://schema.org/eligibleRegion) property can be used:

> […] the geo-political region(s) for which the offer […] is valid.

(With the [`ineligibleRegion`](http://schema.org/ineligibleRegion) property you can list for which location the offer is *not* valid.)

So in Microdata it could look like this:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Product 1</h1>

  <section itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <h2>Offer 1</h2>
    <div itemprop="eligibleRegion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City">…</div>
  </section>

  <section itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <h2>Offer 2</h2>
    <div itemprop="eligibleRegion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City">…</div>
  </section>

</article>
```

The documentation for Google’s [Product Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) doesn’t mention a case where a `Product` has multiple `Offer` items (except for the different case of `AggregateOffer`), so it’s unclear if a Rich Snippet can be displayed in such a case.

Comment: "The documentation for Google’s Product Rich Snippet doesn’t mention a case where a Product has multiple Offer items (except for the different case of AggregateOffer), so it’s unclear if a Rich Snippet can be displayed in such a case."  It can, Unor.  Google will display a price range in such cases, such as "$8-$20".

Comment: I see. Well that's a complete answer, thank you for your time!